# how can I extract the key word following by a word and preceding by a comma using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regexp-substr

my string is like this
`'{ "city": "(not set)", "cityId": "9108665", "continent": "Americas", "country": "United States", "latitude": "0.0000", "longitude": "0.0000", "metro": "(not set)", "networkDomain": "(not set)", "networkLocation": "(not set)", "region": "Pennsylvania", "subContinent": "Northern America" }'`

how can i use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the region, Pennsylvania

i am trying
`select REGEXP_SUBSTR(string,':[^:]+[[:alpha:]]',1,10) as region` however, it doesn't give me what i want.

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `:[^:]+[[:alpha:]]` that you tried matches too much, as the negated character class `[^:]+` matches any char except `:` That match will reach until the next key value pair.

If you just want to select Pennsylvania, you can use a bit more specific pattern to get the capture group value from the 10th match:

```
"[^"]*":\s*"([^"]*)"
```

For example:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('{ "city": "(not set)", "cityId": "9108665", "continent": "Americas", "country": "United States", "latitude": "0.0000", "longitude": "0.0000", "metro": "(not set)", "networkDomain": "(not set)", "networkLocation": "(not set)", "region": "Pennsylvania", "subContinent": "Northern America" }', '"[^"]*":\s*"([^"]*)"',1,10,NULL,1) as region from dual;
```

Output

```
REGION
Pennsylvania
```

[See an Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3fac0862e11b74de5d8686db224335c)

But perhaps it might be easier to add region to the pattern to get a single match from the example data.

```
"region":\s*"([^"]*)"
```

[See another Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d400f781d243757256e8c608fa17b6f6)